# How to push locally created repository to bitbucket repo that's already been initialized

Tags: git, bitbucket

My organization granted repository creation rights only to managers and convicting them to make one takes time and effort. When they do, they usually usethe default option of repo initialized with `.gitignore` file. This prevents me from simply pushing my locally-created repositories with

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:.....
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

giving me:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

while `git pull` ends with:

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Note: I want to keep the local directory intact.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Comment: This question is unrelated and the only common part is generic git message.

Answer (score 0):

Turns just forcing the push was sufficient.

```
git push --force
```